# how to call an aspx and return a string value from the aspx

Tags: asp.net, delphi

I have an aspx that I need to call from Delphi (Berlin).

I need to pass it some parameters. Example:

'aDay', Edit1.Text
'aMonth', Edit2.Text
'aYear',Edit3.Text

When the parameters are sent correctly, the aspx will return a string value.

I am guessing that Indy components may have the answer.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: ASPX runs in an HTTP server (IIS). You can use Indy's `TIdHTTP` component to interact with it. Use the `TIdHTTP.Post()` method to send parameter data to the server. `Post()` has overloads that can return any response data as either a `String` or a `TStream`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to implement this. This could be just one way to do it:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    Response.Write("Hello World");
    Response.End();
}
```

You could also set the content type to `application/json` if you need a json result.

This could be also implemented with a WebAPI endpoint but you asked for an aspx page.